# How to rebuild tokenised data by the original row id?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of tweets that I want to add a row id to, tokenise, manually remove the stop_words from and then re-build them into the original tweets (using their original row_id). Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
tweet_text = c("this is a tweet", "this is tweet 2", "and tweet 3 is here")
tweet_df <- as.data.frame(tweet_text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number())

tweet_tokens <- tweet_df %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, tweet_text, token = "tweets")

#here i remove the stopwords

custom_stop_words <- tibble(word = c("tweet")) #using tweet as an example
colnames(custom_stop_words) <- "word"

tweet_tokens_clean <- tweet_tokens %>% 
  filter(!word %in% custom_stop_words$word)


#at this point I want a new column to be made that would reconstruct the original tweets. So all the obs that have row_id = 1 (because they came from the same original tweet) would be made into one row

#would look like

# row id | tweet_text
# ----------------------------
#    1   | "this is a "
# ---------------------------
#    2   | "this is a 2 "
# ---------------------------
#    3   | "and 3 is here "
```

So my data frame has each tweet marked by 1...2...3 etc but each row is a word. My instinct is pivot_wider() (the tidyr v1 version of spread()) should be able to help here but as I'm not looking to make the values of the variable into columns I can't work out what to do. Similarly, from the documentation melt() or cast() seem like they're along the right lines but I've never used them before and can't quite work it out.

Any help appreciated! TIA.

Comment: First stemm words then remove stop words -- use preexisting packages -- they are good, then you can easily create a dictionary and swap words with tokens with something like `plyr::mapvalues`.

Comment: Hi, can you include a reproducible example along with expected output so that is is easier to understand what you are trying to do. You can read [here on to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @JacobJacox I've amended my original post to include a reproducible example. Hope this is clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `group_by`/`summarize`, using `paste` with the `collapse` argument:

```
tweet_tokens_clean %>%
  group_by(row_id) %>%
  summarize(tweet_text = paste(word, collapse = " "))
```

This works because `paste(x, collapse = " ")` combines the elements of `x` and separates them with spaces:

```
paste(c("hello", "world"), collapse = " ")
# [1] "hello world"
```